# vertical align middle not working with h2 and img tag

Tags: html, css

I have one `div` and `image` and `h2` tag inside that div. I want to align `h2` tag middle vertically. I tried

```
vertical-align:middle
display:table-cell;
```

But not working for me. I don't want to use line height or padding, because some time i have long title, so it need to be center if it wrapped in 2 line. Here is the code,

```html
<div style="float:left;width:100%;margin:10px 43px;">
   <img width="60" style="float:left" src="http://coachfxlive.com/assets/channels/102x102/559bb0556fe02.jpg">
   <h2 style="width: 87%;float: left;margin:0 0 0 10px; vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell; ">Coaching 3-5 year old players</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the floats. Floating takes it out of the normal flow of the document. Also, use `inline-block` instead of `table-cell`. I simplified your code for this demo:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Yyqjxj

```
div{
  max-width: 400px;
}

img, h2{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

<div>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
   <h2>Coaching 3-5 year old players</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: i removed float. and this is the code from result `<div style="max-width: 800px;">
           <img width="60" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;" src="http://coachfxlive.com/assets/channels/102x102/559bb0556fe02.jpg">
           <h2 style="width: 87%; float: left; margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">SoccerPlus - Coaching 3-5 year old players</h2>
          </div>`

Comment: which is not aligned in middle.